# Searchbar implementation of fetchedresultscontroller in swift

Tags: swift, searchbar

The data present in coredata are showing on tableview succesfully. But when i am trying to implement search bar with fetchedresultscontroller it is not working properly. I am adding my code. can anyone check it and help me to fix the issue.
Mycode is -

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections {
        return sections.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections {
        return sections[section].numberOfObjects
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PatientListTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? PatientListTableViewCell
    
    if let patientData = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) {
        cell?.patientName.text = patientData.name
        cell?.patientIdLabel.text = patientData.id
        cell?.location_Lbl.text = patientData.streetAdress
    }
    
    return cell!
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text?.count != 0 {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", searchBar.text!)
        
        fetchedResultsController!.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        
        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
            searching = true
            tableView.reloadData()
        } catch let error as NSError {
        }
    }
    
    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searching = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.endEditing(true)
        searching = false
    }
```

Comment: What's not working exactly? Is that you real code? It seems to have a missing "}". Also,  in the catch, would you mind checking if there is an error? And print it?

Comment: when i am writting something in seach bar it it not updating the tableview. missing "}" is the typing mistake. no there is no error. it is not going to catch block

Comment: In the `do` block, is what's the `fetchedResultsController ` count after the `performFetch()`?

Comment: fetchedResultsController  count is 1